# Computing a description of a set of lattice points

Tags: algorithms

I have an infinite subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}^k$ which I know (or at least strongly suspect) is a finite union of regions, each of which is defined by finitely many linear equalities and inequalities (with integer coefficients). I would like to find an explicit description of $S$, i.e., sets of (in)equalities that define it. Is there a good algorithm for this?

A little more information. The representation I have for $S$ is its indicator function, i.e., I have a function $f \colon \mathbb{N}^k \to \{0,1\}$ such that $f(x)=1$ if and only if $x \in S$. In my case, $k \approx 10$ and $f$ can be computed reasonably efficiently. Obviously, in this generality one cannot verify in a finite computation that a hypothetical description of $S$ is correct. However, for my $S$ I expect the answer to be reasonable, and I have other means to prove a purported description is correct.

Comment: I think you need to give us more information about your set.  You already know that it's not even possible to check an answer in finite time, so how could there be a good general algorithm?

Comment: I don't really know what to say about the set, other than it is probably "reasonable": I expect the coefficients in the inequalities to be rather small, and that if a description seems correct then it probably is correct. So an algorithm is to loop over all sets of inequalities with small coefficients, and check if they give the right answer for all small values of coordinates. I think this would work in theory, but is probably far too slow.

Comment: If your infinite set is a union of regions, and if these regions are disjoint, then you will end up with a non-convex set $S$. You cannot describe a non-convex set with a set of inequalities.

Comment: Wolfgang: sorry, what I wrote may not have been completely clear. I would like to find $T_1, \ldots, T_r$, where each $T_i$ is some finite set of (in)equalities, such that if $S_i$ is the set of lattice points satisfying all (in)equalities in $T_i$, then my set $S$ is the union of the $S_i$. Such $T_i$ exist (assuming $S$ looks how I expect), I'd just like to know an efficient way to find them!